I can't register my app in Firebase App Check on iOS
I am not able to access Firebase App Check. I am developing an application on SwiftUI and decided to connect App Attest . In FireBase console I registered my app and its status says “Registered” . I have written for connection in AppDelegate
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    let providerFactory = YourAppCheckProviderFactory()
    AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
      
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
      print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Обработка регистрации удаленных уведомлений
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // Обработка ошибки регистрации удаленных уведомлений
    print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Обработка полученных уведомлений
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
      completionHandler(.noData)
      return
    }
  }
}


When I run the app on a real phone via Xcode, the console shows this message
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Too many attempts. Underlying error: Не удалось завершить операцию. The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx/apps/xxxxx:exchangeDeviceCheckToken 
 - HTTP status code: 400 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "App not registered: xxxxx",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"

and I can't use it. I rechecked all the Data in Firebase and everything is correct. What do I need to do ?

In your Xcode console logs I see that DeviceCheck was getting used (it's the default). The call to AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(...) needs to happen before calling FirebaseApp.configure() in order to get applied.
In your provided snippet, this would look like:
let providerFactory = YourAppCheckProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)

FirebaseApp.configure()

For the Debug Provider (usable on a simulator or a real phone for testing), this would be:
let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)

FirebaseApp.configure()


Make sure to follow the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider

I actually used Debug Token and everything started working. The only thing is that the documentation says that “App Check would normally not classify as valid, such as a simulator during development, or from a continuous integration (CI) environment,” . If I run an application via Xcode, but on a real phone. Is this considered a simulator or not?

If this is really a simulator, then how can I test on a real phone without a Debug token?

The instructions at  https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider are now updated to clarify that debug tokens are useful for development (only!) whether developing on simulator or device.
